# Const constructor create non-const class objects?

Tags: dart

The following code got error `Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.`:

```
class TestConst {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  TestConst(this.x, this.y);
}


void main() {

  TestConst myconst1 = const TestConst(1,2);
  TestConst myconst2 = const TestConst(1,2);

  print(identical(myconst1, myconst2));

}
```

while the following didn't, and strangely `identical(myconst1, myconst2)` return `false` when `TestConst` indeed only has const-constructor? :

```
class TestConst {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  const TestConst(this.x, this.y);
}


void main() {

  TestConst myconst1 = TestConst(1,2);
  TestConst myconst2 = TestConst(1,2);

  print(identical(myconst1, myconst2));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` on a constructor means that the constructor *can* create a `const` object (if the callsite opts in and if all of the construction arguments are also `const`), not that it only creates `const` objects.

The [Language Tour does mention this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constant-constructors) (but not in much detail):

> Constant constructors don’t always create constants. For details, see the section on [using constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors).

...

> Some classes provide [constant constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constant-constructors). To create a compile-time constant using a constant constructor, put the `const` keyword before the constructor name:

And if you're wondering why a constructor declared with `const` still needs `const` to be explicitly specified when invoked, see: [Dart: Is there a disadvantage to using const constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607745/)