# Dart: Is there a disadvantage to using const constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is an analyzer/lint check to warn me when it is possible to use a `const` constructor: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_constructors.html

(ie. using `final a = const A();` instead of `final a = A();`)

I think to understand the advantages (there will only ever be one instance with the same constant values for a const constructor). But why isn't this the default? Since dart 2 the `new` can be omitted, so why didn't they change the definition of creating a new instance which can be created `const` simply as `const` instead of `new`? I assume there must be some disadvantage to having everything `const`?

(for example in a constant context like `const [A()]` it is actually the same as `const [const A()]`, so why not everywhere)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744677/how-does-the-const-constructor-actually-work

Comment: @CopsOnRoad maybe i'm blind but I still can't find any downsides of using `const` (when it is possible) in the linked question/answers or in the linked blog post?

Comment: one of the downside of using `const` is you have to make all the instance variable `final`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad this is not a downside of using a `const` instance, just a requirement for a `const` constructor. When I'm using a class which has a `const` constructor (e.g. flutter's `SizedBox`) why would I ever want `SizedBox(height: 8)` (with `new`) instead of `const`?

Comment: Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21746692/6618622) a read.

Comment: I did. But it did not answer my question. To be more specific: Where is the disadvantage of using `const SizedBox(height: 8)` vs. `new SizedBox(height: 8)`? (I think I understand the advantages, but not the disadvantages)

Comment: I don't think there is any significant disadvantage of using `const SizedBox(...)` over `new SizedBox(...)`.  There are only advantages. `const` is superior than `new` in terms of performance, and except some limitations of `const` like non-final fields not possible etc, there is no disadvantage of using it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> so why didn't they change the definition of creating a new instance which can be created `const` simply as `const` instead of `new`?

If you mean why doesn't `final a = A();` automatically assume `const A()` if `A` has a `const` constructor:

1. Sometimes it *is* automatic:

   ```dart
   const a = A();
   ```

   in which case `A`'s constructor is being invoked in a `const` context and doesn't need an extra `const` qualifier on the right-hand-side.
2. An explicit `const` expresses *intent*. For example, suppose you had:

   ```dart
   final a = A(B());
   ```

   where `A` and `B` have `const` constructors.  Later, somebody makes a change:

   ```dart
   final a = A(C());
   ```

   where `C` does *not* have a `const` constructor.  If `const` were automatic, then you would have no idea that `a` is no longer `const`.  Maybe that's okay, but it also could suddenly have a negative impact on your application's performance, and without an explicit `const` qualifier, the impact of a local change could have a much wider scope than expected. (That said, *explicit* `const` qualifiers and automatically adding them aren't mutually exclusive.)
3. `const` *can* have downsides. `const` creates *compile-time* constants.  If you have:

   ```dart
   final a1 = A();
   final a2 = A();
   ```

   `identical(a1, a2)` is not true.  If `const A()` were implicit, then `identical(a1, a2)` *would* be true, and maybe that's not a property that the code intended to have.
4. Compile-time constants live forever.  The whole point is to have an object that can be reused instead of re-constructing it.  The flipside is that won't be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, i think especially 3&4 make perfect sense. Probably important to keep that in mind when using `Expando`, if `const` objects are never destroyed. Never made that connection, even though it's documented there.