# Any performance gain when using "instantiating" objects using `const` in Dart 2 / Flutter?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart, constants

In Dart 2, the keyword `new` and `const` are no longer needed to instantiate an object. For example, `new ListView(...)` is now equivalent to `ListView(...)`.

However, some class constructors are declared `const`, including most Flutter widgets, like `Text`:

```
const Text(
    String this.data, {
    Key? key,
    this.style,
    // ...
    this.textHeightBehavior,
})
```

Then, to instantiate a `Text`, we can type either `Text('hi!')`, or `const Text('hi!')`.

My question: Is there any difference in terms of performance or the compiled code between those two?

Note:

The usage of `const` at the call site is more prominent at certain places, for example in Android Studio, if we choose to "Wrap with Padding", the `EdgeInsets.all` constructor call uses `const`:

```
 Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Text('hi!'),
 ),
```

Comment: `const` is not automatic.  You must use it explicitly use it to create compile-time constants.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607745/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always try to use `const` when possible, especially if you're creating a Flutter app. Constant constructors are very important because they're used to "cache" widgets so that they won't be unnecessarily rebuilt.

---

Imagine you had list of 10k items in your Flutter app:

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('My items:'),
        
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 10000,
          itemBuilder: (_, i) => SomeComplexWidget(
            value: i,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

There are a lot of factors that could trigger a widget rebuild but let's assume that you simply rotated your device screen a few times. With this code...

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  height: 400,
  child: Example(),
),
```

... you aren't using a `const` constructor so you're rebuilding `Example` on **every** rebuild (= you're also unnecessarily rebuilding the `Column`, the `ListView`, and re-rendering a few `SomeComplexWidget`). `ListView.builder` is a lazy initializer so it will save you a bit but you still don't want it to always be rebuilt.

If you used a `Column()` or a plain `ListView()` constructor for your list, it would have affected performance even more (more jank and thus more skipped frames). If you did this instead...

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  height: 400,
  child: const Example(),
),
```

... you would "cache" the `Example` widget (meaning that it will be built only **once**). As you can guess, this is a very simple but important performance optimization you can do. Using constant constructors is not just my word but it's officially recommended by the docs:

- [StatelessWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) docs (see **Performance considerations**)
- [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) docs (see **Performance considerations**)

Note that if your widget contained something that depends on `InheritedWidget`, the `const` keyword wouldn't have effect (otherwise, the widget couldn't "listen" for changes on the inherited widget".

---

**Bonus**

In Flutter, you can also cache widgets "manually". When you cannot use `const`, you can use `late` (or `late final`) inside the state to cache the widget. Look at this example:

```dart
class OtherExample extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Interests> interests;
  const OtherExample({
    required this.interests,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('My list'),
   
        MyInterestsList(
          data: interests,
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

You want `MyInterestsList` to be cached because it never changes but `const` doesn't work here (since `interests` is **not** a compile-time) constant. When you can't use `const` but you still want to cache a widget, do it manually:

```dart
class OtherExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Interests> interests;
  const OtherExample({
    required this.interests,
  });

  @override
  _OtherExampleState createState() => _OtherExampleState();
}

class _OtherExampleState extends State<OtherExample> {
  late Widget myInterests = MyInterestsList(
     data: widget.interests,
  );

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(OtherExample oldWidget) { 
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    // This makes sure that the interests list is updated ONLY when
    // it actually changes
    if (widget.interests != oldWidget.interests) {
      myInterests = MyInterestsList(
        data: widget.interests,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Text('My list'),
   
        myInterests,
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks to `late` you're caching your widget inside the state class. Thanks to the `didUpdateWidget` override, the `MyInterestsList` widget will **only** be rebuilt when the list changes. If the list never changes, `MyInterestsList` will never be rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! Also, TIL that `late` does a lazy initialization. (I came from Kotlin and thought that `late` is just equivalent to `lateinit` in Kotlin. Turned out that `late` can also mean *lazy* initialization.)